# Should I use both gtag.js and GTM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I´m a bit confused with Google Tag Manager and gtag.js. I have read a lot about it, but It´s not 100% clear to me what to use in my case.

Historically, we have been using gtag.js in our **AngularJS** webapp. We also used the library **angularytics** to track Google Ads conversions of purchases providing dynamically prices and leads directly from our website.

We have migrated to GTM to provide third party libraries from the GTM interface. This means that we have commented/removed gtag.js. Now, we track page analytics from GTM. However, obviously, our angularytics calls to Google Ads conversion tracking using gtag.js has stopped working.

At this poing I´m very confused with some questions:

- I have read that I can add Google ads conversion tracking using GTM setting up conversions one by one. But, is it possible to set the price of each product which is totally dynamic? Or this case should I use gtag?
- Does GTM provide a library to replace gtag functions? From the SEO optimazation point of view, I think would be interesting to avoid loading two libraries gtm and gtag.
- Is there any problem that both libraries live together?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can think of GTM as a service where you can dynamically change the included tags in a website without direct access to the production source code. This is for example widely used for marketing agencies whose clients won't give away access to their servers. But it doesn't really have anything to do with Google Analytics at all as you can insert tags from any service provider (Social pixels, Intercom-like services...)

If you use Google Tag Manager to handle those tags you should remove the script call from your code. Otherwise it will be invoked twice

Comment: Yes, I get the differences. But the point is, let´s say that I use GTM and remove the script calls from gtag. My products are boats. Each one has a different price and you can even provide discounts. This means that I cannot set a short catalogue of products with a value one by one. However, I would like to track the purchase conversions in Google Ads with the price value. Can I do this just using GTM? I see that I can add a value, but is a fixed value.

Comment: I still don't get what has to do with GTM tbh. You can do this with GA, independently of how you import it in the website, using a script tag or GTM. Is how to achieve the dynamic price thing your question?

Comment: Ok. Let´s try to clarify the questions one by one. First question: Is it possible to set the prices of each product when you have more than 15.000 products with discounts which are totally dynamic using GTM?